# Scalar and Return type declarations can be used at the same time?

Tags: php, class, oop, php-7

I'm coding a PHP class using new features in PHP 7 and later. So,

1. Can I use scalar and return type declarations at the same time?
2. If yes, is it a good practice to use them at the same time or should I avoid? Can you explain with examples?

Here is a simple example structure of my class:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

class ExampleClass {
    public function exampleMethod(int $a, int $b): int {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why couldn't you? Have you tried it? 2) questions about "good practice" tend to be opinionated and so they are off-topic for SO

Comment: 1) I've tried and no any errors/warnings. That's OK. 2) I've no idea which is the best approach. That's why I wanted to hear from you. If you provide some opinion I can make my own way to go.

Comment: That's not what this site is for though. You're looking for a discussion site; this is a Q&A site, where the Qs are, ideally, concrete programming problems. E.g. "here is my code, why does line 23 do X instead of Y." See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use scalar and return type declarations at the same time, these are new features introduced in PHP7.

You have declared `declare(strict_types=1);` at the top of file that means :

> This means that the strictness of typing for scalars is configured on a per-file basis. This directive not only affects the type declarations of parameters, but also a function's return type

For more detail, check the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

Also, check type declaration [PHP Manual Type Declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: Can you share your personal thoughts about the second question?